# Bin sequential values in list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the list:

```
new_maks = [75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91]
```

I want to bin the elements into areas where the next element are sequentially increased by 1. My initial idea is basically to initialize two lists `bin_start` and `bin_end` and iterate through `new_maks` to check for sequential values.

```
bin_start = []
bin_end = []

counter = 0
for i in range(len(new_maks)):
    if new_maks[i] == new_maks[0]:
        bin_start.append(new_maks[i])

    elif (new_maks[i] - new_maks[i-1]) ==1:
        try:
            bin_end[counter] = new_maks[i]
        except:
            bin_end.append(new_maks[i])

    elif (new_maks[i] - new_maks[i-1]) >1:

        if new_maks[i] != new_maks[-1]:
            bin_start.append(new_maks[i])
            counter +=1
```

Which produces the desired result of:

```
bin_start= [75, 85]
bin_end = [81, 89]
```

Is there a simpler/vectorized way to achieve this result?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney  Not duplicate as I am looking for a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's for performance efficiency with NumPy tools -

```
def start_stop_seq1(a):
    m = np.r_[False,np.diff(a)==1,False]
    return a[m[:-1]!=m[1:]].reshape(-1,2).T
```

Sample run -

```
In [34]: a # input array
Out[34]: 
array([ 75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  91,
        92,  93, 100, 101, 110])

In [35]: start_stop_seq1(a)
Out[35]: 
array([[ 75,  85,  91, 100],
       [ 81,  89,  93, 101]])
```

**Alternative #1 : One liner with one more `np.diff`**

We can go one step further to achieve *compactness* -

```
In [43]: a[np.diff(np.r_[False,np.diff(a)==1,False])].reshape(-1,2).T
Out[43]: 
array([[ 75,  85,  91, 100],
       [ 81,  89,  93, 101]])
```

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for.  indexing an array with two `np.diff`'s is some next-level business.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way could be to use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import groupby, count

counter = count(1)
new_mask = [75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]

generator = ((first, last) for key, (first, *_, last) in groupby(new_mask, key=lambda val: val - next(counter)))
bin_start, bin_end = zip(*generator)

print(bin_start)
print(bin_end)
```

**Output**

```
(75, 85)
(81, 89)
```

This is based in an old itertools [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples). If you fancy pandas you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

new_mask = [75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]

s = pd.Series(data=new_mask)
result = s.groupby(s.values - s.index).agg(['first', 'last'])
bin_start, bin_end = zip(*result.itertuples(index=False))

print(bin_start)
print(bin_end)
```

Again this is based on the principle that consecutive increasing (by 1) values will have the same difference against an running sequence. As mentioned in the linked documentation:

> The key to the solution is differencing with a range so that
>   consecutive numbers all appear in same group.